# What is the meaning of the "<" operator?

Tags: c++

In the following code for a binary search tree:

```
template <class TKey>
class bst<TKey>::node *bst<TKey>::insert(node *T, TKey &key)
{
  if (T == NULL) {
    T = new node;
    T->key = key;
  } else if (T->key == key) {
    cout << "key " << key << " already in tree" << endl;
  } else {
    
    int dir = T->key < key;
    T->link[dir] = insert(T->link[dir], key);   
  }
  return T;
}
```

I'm confused what the line

```
int dir = T->key < key;
```

is doing. I could understand `int dir = T->key`, although of course that wouldn't make sense, but I've not seen the `<` operator used in that way before. Any clues?

Comment: '<' is  'less than'  : the line assigns a boolean 0 or 1  to an int, which presumably if you turn up warnings would be flagged?

Comment: all conditional operators return either `0` or `1`. For exmpl: `int a = 1 == 0;` will assign `0` in `a`. And in same way `int a = a == a;` will assign `1` in `a`. It works for all conditional operator in same way

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`T->key < key` is a condition. It will evaluate to either `true` or `false`.
If it evaluates to `true`, `dir` will get value `1`, otherwise it will get value `0`.

```
int dir = T->key < key;
```

is short form for writing

```
int dir;
if(T->key < key)
    dir = 1;
else
    dir = 0;
```

When a `boolean` is assigned to an `int`, it gets the value `0` or `1` corresponding to `false` or `true`.

Answer (score 6):

If the operator isn't overloaded, than it has the usual meaning; it evaluates to either `true` or `false`. This is a `bool` type, and therefore can be implicitly converted to an `int`.

However, if `TKey` is a class and overloads it, or there's a global overload, then we've no idea what it does unless we see the code.

Comment: +! for raising the possibility of an overload, which could have a non-boolean return type.

Answer (score 0):

`<` returns 1 if the first operand is less than the second operand, or 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The `<` operator is a boolean comparison operator - i.e. it evaluates to `0` if the condition is false, and `1` if the condition is true. It's usually used in conditionals, but using the return value directly is perfectly valid. In this case, if the value of `T->key` is less than the value of `key`, `dir` will be `1` otherwise `dir` will be `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as the binary search tree stores values lesser than root on left and greater values on right, you need select which direction the insertion is gonna take place. To do this you are comparing the key with the current node's value. The result of this comparison is stored in dir variable. So if key is lesser than T's value, dir gets 1 which represents left side in the link[] that holds pointers to the left and right branches of the node T.  And then insertion is done recursively with the left node of T. That is why you do a comparison there. Just to see whether we must insert the element to the right or left of the current node.